# MUI Datagrid truncating tables

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I am currently developing a site where I am showing some data in a table. For that, I am using

`@mui/x-data-grid`
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/

and I am experiencing the following issue:

[image: example]

Basically, it seems that the width for each column is being truncated, normally to 100px which is the `minWidth` default value. I don't usually know how big this field could be so, using `minWidth` does not accomplish the solution as it keeps shortening the data at some point.

Is there any way to avoid this?

For example, in the image above, if the reference `Q-24` is something like `Q-12345678901234567890`, it may end up truncated to `Q-1234567...`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building my own component as it doesn't seem there is a built-in solution to my requirements.